# Spring Integration - Dynamic TCP Factory and Channel Connections

Tags: sockets, dynamic, tcp, spring-integration, loading

Is there anyway to programatically create TCP-Connection factories and TCP-IObound-Channel adapters.

I am creating an applicaiton which has the TCP connection details in its database. And TCP connections are expected to grow. The increase in connectivity is required to be free of server restarts. i.e. if a new TCP server connection detail is inserted in to DB, the application should programtically pick the connection details and start TCP communication using the Spring Integration when required, and there shouldn't be application restart for this purpose.

Currently I have 5 TCP clients, in my application, connecting to different TCP serverSockets. I am maintaining 5 XML files for each connection. But this does not supports the scalability, as for each new serverSocket i have to add a new  configurations file in my application and need to restart it.

Comment: can you show me your sample  code I am also having more TCP clients, in my application, connecting to different TCP serverSocket ?

Comment: @Shailesh please visit this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062895/spring-integration-tcp-get-connection-id-of-the-connected-clients/39062897#39062897

Comment: @Shailesh. Let me know if u need more clarification.

Comment: AbstractServerConnectionFactory connFactory = (AbstractServerConnectionFactory) appContext.getBean("server");
List<String> openConns = connFactory.getOpenConnectionIds();  how did you created these number of connections ?

Comment: These connections get created once a tcp client comments to this tcp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [dynamic-ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) which does this for ftp outbound adapters.

Essentially, it uses a custom router to create a new application context for the adapter on-demand.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388816/how-dynamic-create-ftp-adapter-in-spring-integration) which has links to other answers about doing a similar thing on the inbound side for mail adapters, this time using Java configuration.

**EDIT**

In response to the comment below.

For normal request/reply processing, using an inbound gateway, the framework will take care of routing the service activator reply to the correct socket. It does this by using the connection id header.

If you need to provide arbitrary replies (e.g. more than one reply for a message, you have to use inbound and outbound channel adapters and your application is responsible for setting up the connection id header.

There are two ways to access the required header in a POJO invoked by a service activator:

```
public void foo(byte[] payload, @Header(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID) String connectionId) {
    ...
}

public void foo(Message<byte[]> message) {
    String connectionId = message.getHeaders().get(...);
}
```

Then, when you send your replies, you need to set that header somehow.

Comment: Hi Garry, I have a problem here with the above dynamic TCP connection approach. When a message is received, I want to get the TCP connection details for the received message. this way I can keep track in my application of the sender sending that message. But in Service activator I am not able to get this detail. Also need the connection details when my TCP client is expecting a reply from a server. For info my application has more than one TCP clients and servers.

Comment: You should really ask a new question for that; but see my edit.

Comment: Sorry. I have posted it as a question NOW. Thanks for your kind and prompt responses to my query.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062895/spring-integration-tcp-get-connection-id-of-the-connected-clients/39062897#39062897