# Spring integration initialize a list of service activators at runtime

Tags: spring-integration

I m new to Spring Integration and We have a requirement where we need to have  listeners initialized for a given set of directories dynamically at runtime.  Directory list will be updated periodically in a property file and Service activators and queue channels need to initialized for each directories on this list.

For examples directories list can be Dir1,Dir2,Dir3. This directories list can change in future. A new directory can be added or an existing directory can be
removed.

At runtime based on the list provided in the properties file, I need to create a service activator dynamically with queue channel associated for each one of them. Is there an viable option available in Spring Integration to achieve this requirement ? Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [runtime flow registration](https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/08/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-m1-and-1-1-3-are-available) provided by the upcoming 1.2 release of the [java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl).

Also, take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388816/how-dynamic-create-ftp-adapter-in-spring-integration) - it has links for another mechanism to create multiple inbound mail adapters programmatically.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the direction. Runtime flow registration seems to be an interesting option.. Let me give it a shot. Thanks again