# Setting multiple inbound-channel-adapter at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Using spring-integration-sftp, what is the recommended way to create an arbitrary number of inbound-channel-adapter objects?  My application needs to monitor multiple remote directories (1 to n), which will not be known until runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way with current technology is to use [the Java DSL "Dynamic and runtime Integration Flows"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#java-dsl-runtime-flows).

Each flow is programmatically registered with the `IntegrationFlowContext`.

Also see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388816/how-dynamic-create-ftp-adapter-in-spring-integration) and its links for other techniques.

Comment: It's very sad that all the links to the docs on various answers are now rendered useless with a 404

Comment: This is true; but the documentation creation technology has changed and the anchors are different. You can always go to the [root URL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) (remove the anchor) and then search the table of contents for the subject matter. We do fix the links in these answers when people point them out.