# how to dynamically register Feed Inbound Adapter in Spring Integration?

Tags: rss, spring-integration, dsl, atom-feed, enterprise-integration

I'm trying to implement an RSS/Atom feed aggregator in `spring-integration` and I am primarily using the Java DSL to write my `IntegrationFlow`. A requirement of this aggregator is that feeds can be added / removed during runtime. That is to say, the feeds are **not known** at design time.

I found it simple to use the basic `Feed.inboundAdapter()` with a test url and extract the links out of the feed with a transformer and then pass it on to an `outbound-file-adapter` to save the links to a file. However, I have gotten very stuck when trying to read the (thousands) of feed urls from an `inbound-file-adapter` run the file through a `FileSplitter` and then pass each resulting `Message<String>` containing the feed url to then register a new `Feed.inboundAdapter()`. Is this not possible with the Java DSL?

Ideally I would love it if I could do the following:

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow getFeedsFromFile() throws MalformedURLException {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inboundFileChannel(), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10000)))
            .handle(new FileSplitter())
            //register new Feed.inboundAdapter(payload.toString()) foreach Message<String> containing feed url coming from FileSplitter
            .transform(extractLinkFromFeedEntry())
            .handle(appendLinkToFile())
            .get();
}
```

Though after reading through the spring integration java DSL code multiple times (and learning a tonne of stuff along the way) I just can't see that it's possible to do it this way. So... A) is it? B) should it be? C) Suggestions?

It almost feels like I should be able to take the output of `.handle(new FileSplitter())` and pass that into `.handleWithAdapter(Feed.inboundAdapter(/*stuff here*/))` but the DSL only references `outbound-adapter`s there. Inbound adapters are really just a subclass of `AbstractMessageSource` and it seems the **only** place you can specify one of those is as an argument to the `IntegrationFlows.from(/*stuff here*/)` method.

I would have thought it would be possible to take the input from a file, split it line by line, use that output to register inbound feed adapters, poll those feeds, extract the new links from feeds as they appear and append them to a file. It appears as though it's not.

Is there some clever subclassing I can do to make this work??

Failing that... and I suspect this is going to be the answer, I found the spring integration [Dynamic Ftp Channel Resolver Example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/ftp/DynamicFtpChannelResolver.java) and [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/117523-starting-multiple-consumers) answer on how to adapt it dynamically register stuff for the inbound case...

So is this the way to go? Any help/guidance appreciated. After pouring over the DSL code and reading documentation for days, I think I'll have a go at implementing the dynamic ftp example and adapting it to work with FeedEntryMessageSource... in which case my question is... that dynamic ftp example works with XML configuration, but is it possible to do it with either Java config or the Java DSL?

**Update**

I've implemented the solution as follows:

```java
@SpringBootApplication 
class MonsterFeedApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext parent = SpringApplication.run(MonsterFeedApplication.class, args);

    parent.setId("parent");
    String[] feedUrls = {
            "https://1nichi.wordpress.com/feed/",
            "http://jcmuofficialblog.com/feed/"};

    List<ConfigurableApplicationContext> children = new ArrayList<>();
    int n = 0;
    for(String feedUrl : feedUrls) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext child = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        child.setId("child" + ++n);
        children.add(child);
        child.setParent(parent);
        child.register(DynamicFeedAdapter.class);
        StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("feed.url", feedUrl);
        PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("feed", props);
        env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
        child.setEnvironment(env);
        child.refresh();
    }

    System.out.println("Press any key to exit...");
    System.in.read();
    for (ConfigurableApplicationContext child : children) {
        child.close();
    }
    parent.close();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow aggregateFeeds() {       
    return IntegrationFlows.from("feedChannel")
            .transform(extractLinkFromFeed())
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel feedChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public AbstractPayloadTransformer<SyndEntry, String> extractLinkFromFeed() {
    return new AbstractPayloadTransformer<SyndEntry, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String transformPayload(SyndEntry payload) throws Exception {
            return payload.getLink();
        }
    };

}

}
```

DynamicFeedAdapter.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class DynamicFeedAdapter {

    @Value("${feed.url}")
    public String feedUrl;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow feedAdapter() throws MalformedURLException {

        URL url = new URL(feedUrl);

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(s -> s.feed(url, "feedTest"), 
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(10000)))
                .channel("feedChannel")
                .get();
    }

}
```

And this works **IF** and only **IF** I have **one** of the urls defined in `application.properties` as `feed.url=[insert url here]`. Otherwise it fails telling me 'unable to resolve property {feed.url}'. I suspect what is happening there is that the `@Bean`s defined in `DynamicFeedAdapter.java` all get singletons eagerly initialized, so aside from the beans being manually created in our for loop in the main method (which work fine because they have feed.url property injected) we have a stray singleton that has been eagerly initialized and if there is no feed.url defined in application.properties then it can't resolve the property and everything goes bang. Now from what I know of Spring, I know it should be possible to `@Lazy` initialize the beans in `DynamicFeedAdapter.java` so we don't wind up with this one unwanted stray singleton problem-child. The problem is now...if I just mark the `feedAdapter()` `@Lazy` then the beans never get initialized. How do I initialize them myself?

**Update - problem solved**

> Without having tested it, I think the problem is that boot is finding
>   the DynamicFeedAdapter during its component scan. A simple solution is
>   to move it to a sibling package. If MonsterFeedApplication is in
>   com.acme.foo, then put the adapter config class in com.acme.bar. That
>   way, boot won't consider it "part" of the application

This was indeed the problem. After implementing Gary's suggestion, everything works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826864/spring-multiple-imapadapter) and [its follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890833/message-channels-one-or-many) for a similar question about inbound mail adapters.

In essence, each feed adapter is created in a child context that is parameterized.

In that case the child contexts are created in a `main()` method but there's no reason it couldn't be done in a service invoked by `.handle()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gary. I've implemented the solution as per the first link you referenced and I'm getting an issue with the injected properties. I'm doing everything the same as in the example, so creating the child context, setting the parent, setting up the properties, setting them on the environment, then set the environment on the child and refresh. I also have a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer @Bean in my `DynamicFeedAdapter.class` which is the class I'm calling register() on. It keeps saying 'Could not resolve placeholder 'feed.url' in string value "${feed.url}".

Comment: Edit your question with your current code. I probably won't be able to look at it tonight though, but I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Cool, yeah I will do later on when I get home from work. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi Gary, I added my code. I managed to diagnose the problem myself after getting a hunch an eagerly initialized singleton without the property it needs was being instantiated. As a work around I put one of the feed urls in application.properties and the thing actually works (hoorah!). If you could just help me understand how to properly lazy initialize the beans so I don't get the unwanted singleton that is causing the problem, then I'll mark this as the accepted answer. You've been a big help.

Comment: Without having tested it, I think the problem is that boot is finding the `DynamicFeedAdapter` during its component scan. A simple solution is to move it to a sibling package. If `MonsterFeedApplication` is in `com.acme.foo`, then put the adapter config class in `com.acme.bar`. That way, boot won't consider it "part" of the application.

Comment: Cool, i'll give that a go and report back later.

Comment: It works! Perfect solution. Excellent support by the Spring team. Really happy I could finally accomplish this. That one would have continued to stump me for awhile. Gary, would you happen to know which class(es) in boot I need to look at to better understand the component scan / why this problem occurred, so I can deepen my knowledge of boot?

Comment: It's not really Boot, it's Spring - `@SpringBootApplication` is meta-annotated with a "naked" `@ComponentScan`; from its javadocs: `If specific
packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the
class that declares this annotation.`. Since `@Configuration` classes are `@Component`s, any such classes in the same package as the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` will be discovered during app initialization.