# Need to Create File inbound channel adapter dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new in spring integration. So please help me to resolve this problem.

Requirement is something like, we have `multiple location` from where we have to read the files and in future it can increase, location can be Any file system, so I am trying to use `file inbound channel adapter` to complete this requirement.

we can have multiple locations stored in our data base like `pooling time and location` from where we have to pool to get the files.

But if I go with `xml configuration` so I have to create new file inbound channel adapter every time in the xml configuration and all the details. if we want to pool that specific location to get the files. something like below -

```
int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="AdapterOne" prevent-duplicates="false" 
               directory="${FileInputLoc}" filter="compositeFilter"
int:poller fixed-rate="${poolingTime}"
int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
int:service-activator input-channel="AdapterOne" ref="testbean"
bean id="testbean" class="com.SomeActivatorClass"
```

Please suggest me, how can I achieve this by code. so that based on data base row it create different channel adapter which pool at different time to different location.

Thanks,
Ashu

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472229/load-multiple-spring-instances-at-runtime/36477627#36477627) to a similar question - although your question is not exactly a duplicate, it requires the same answer, but the moderators here would not let me answer identically.