# Is it best practice to design Spring Application in such a way that we need to create same context multiple times?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-integration

I am going to start a new project using Spring framework. As I dont have much experience in Spring I need your help to sort out few confusions.

**Lets look at use case**

My application uses Spring integration framework. The core functionality of my app is,

1. I need to poll multiple directories from file system,
2. read the files(csv mostly),
3. process some operations on them and insert them to database.

Currently I have set up spring integration flow for it. Which has `inbound-chaneell-adapter` for polling and then file traverse through the channels and at the end inserted into database.

**My concerns are**

1. Number of directories application supposed to poll will be decided at runtime. Hence I need to create `inbound-chanell-adapter` at runtime (as one chanell adapter can poll only one directory at once) and cant define them statically in my **spring context xml** (As I dont know the how many I need).
2. Each directory has certain properties which should be applied to the file while processing.(While going through the integration flow)
3. So right now what I am doing is I am loading `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml");` for each directory. And cache the required properties in that newly created context. And use them at the time of processing (in `<int:service-activator>`).

**Drawbacks of current design**

1. Separate context is created for each directory.
2. Unnecessary beans are duplicated. (Database session factories and like)

So is there any way to design the application in such a way that context will not be duplicated. And still I can use properties of each directory throughout the integration flow at the same time???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just create a factory which creates as many `inbound-channel-adapters` as you need. Never recreate a context as in the end you will run into strange memory, transaction issues etc.

Comment: @MDeinum, Yes I can create factory for it but still not sure how should I pass corresponding properties throughout the channell flow. ????Every directory has specific properties upon which some operations supposed to perform on message payload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [dynamic ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) and the links in its readme about creating child contexts when needed, containing new inbound components.

Also see my answer to a [similar question for multiple IMAP mail adapters using Java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826864/spring-multiple-imapadapter/32827733#32827733) and then a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890833/message-channels-one-or-many/32891671#32891671).

You can also use a message source advice to reconfigure the `FileReadingMessageSource` on each poll to look at different directories. See [Smart polling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Creating parent-child context look good option. I will be using that one.