# How to dynamically create multiple jms message driven channel adapter based on configuration

Tags: java, spring-integration

Here is my requirement, which have more than 50 inbound consumer  to listen different queues needs to be configured.

Is there any option in spring integration, where I can pass my queue details from configuration and the corresponding consumer bean should be created and added to my application context.

Between, I'm using java 8 with spring 4.3.4

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Use the Java DSL and it's dynamic integration flow feature - see [this question and its first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493071/dynamically-instantiating-spring-integration-flows).

Comment: Oops! I have answered this way already here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose we have implemented [Dynamic Flows Registration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows).

I understand that you might not use Spring Integration Java DSL, but there is no an easy way to register beans at runtime.

An `IntegrationFlowContext` is available for Spring Integration 4.3.x as well: you need to include an extension for the Spring Integration Java DSL: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/

This way you can do something like this in the code:

```
 IntegrationFlow flow = f -> 
          IntegrationFlows.from(
               Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(this.connectionFactory)
                    .destination(aDestinationName))
                 .channel(channelToSend)
                 get();

    IntegrationFlowRegistration theFlow = this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();
```

Comment: Hello Artem, could you please suggest us  how header enricher also adds upon to above flow and I hope each message driven adaptor channel needs  individual outbound channel to put the jms message.

Do we dynamically need to create message channel aswell ? If so, how can dynamically add message channel to my context .

Comment: Why did you take accept from the answer off! That’s not how StackOverflow works. I believe that I answered to your original question. The header enricher deserves its own SO thread. More over that was a holiday here, so I was out off the Internet. Please, study SO policies how to handle questions

Comment: Okay.. have accepted the answer. 
Got the header enricher part working to my requirement. Thanks for your reply.