# Dynamic Spring Boot-Integration configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I would like to migrate a multi-threaded application in JSE to Spring Integration but I have to clarify some points before. First of all, the application will have the following Spring integration components:

- JMS to Transformer to router to TCPOut
- TcpIn (to router) to Transformer to  JMS

In this context, I have to load all the TCP connections **dynamically from a configuration file**. I saw a couple of example of this here in StackOverflow (based in the FTP sample). These samples could be enough for the first part but I am looking for how to do that in Spring Boot and what is the best (and elegant) way to create this type of configuration.

Finally, I have to access to each different context (this is maybe the most important) from a type of Swing monitor to start/stop manually this TCP connections. Is this possible? What do you suggest me to do?

All my current components are java based configuration (not DSL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826864/spring-multiple-imapadapter) and [its follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890833/message-channels-one-or-many) for examples of how to dynamically create application contexts using Java Configuration.

Also, take a look at the [new feature in the Java DSL](https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/08/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-m1-and-1-1-3-are-available) for dynamically registering/removing integration flows with the context. The 1.2 version of the DSL, containing this feature, will be released shortly.

You can stop/start endpoints using JMX or a control bus, or programmatically.

Comment: Is Java DSL mandatory for dynamically registering elements or just an improvement?. I am not really familiarized with it and I prefer to keep the java configuration. I like the idea to manage the elements with a control bus. Any idea of how to start with this?

Comment: Ok. I´ve got  the idea of different contexts but I do not have a clear vision of how to access to see the status of each loaded component in each child.

Comment: Use `context.getBean("someAdapter", SmartLifecycle.class);` to get a reference to the bean - `SmartLifecycle` has methods `isRunning()`, `start()`, `stop()`. To use a control bus, add one to each context and send messages to it (`context.getBean("controlBusChannel", MessageChannel.class);`

Comment: Thank you Gary, I will try this soon.

Comment: The problem that I am seeing is Spring Boot. It loads the environment from Main.class with the whole Configuration classes. This will raise an exception because the child Value annotation will not be created.

Comment: I can't speculate what your issue is. You need to edit your question (or preferably ask another) showing an example of the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: `IntegrationFlowContext` is the winner! I don't think it is appropriate to create many child contexts just to create several message sources based on config properties. It is an ugly hack imho.