# FTP component with dynamic properties

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

How could I use message headers to set properties like `host`, `user`, `password`, etc in the `SessionFactory`? Is it possible?

In my case, these data are retrieved from database and stored as message headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [dynamic-ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) - it creates a sub-flow for each destination and uses a dynamic router.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826864/spring-multiple-imapadapter) and it's [follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890833/message-channels-one-or-many) have examples using java configuration (albeit for mail adapters rather than FTP).