# dynamic inbound / outbound configuration in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Thinking to use Spring Integration for dynamic Inbound / Outbound configuration. There can be 'n' number of customers using our system, each of them will have their own inbound FTP / webservice configuration to pull files for processing into our system. Likewise after processing each of those customers can have outbound FTP / webservice configuration where the reports (end result) need to be pushed. Is spring integration appropriate for such cases? if yes, can you please suggest or point to any of the examples. Webservice includes both REST and SOAP. 
Also, instead of polling at fixed interval, can each customer have their own cron expression as to when to pull the files during Inbound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use-case looks fully as an appropriate for the [Spring Cloud Data Flow](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/).

Each customer will configure a `stream` with desired options for each module.

Otherwise your question looks very broad and it has a big chance to be closed here.

Answer (score 0):

See the [dynamic ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced) (XML configuration). This is outbound; see the readme for some links about doing it the same way for inbound.

[See this answer - mail inbound adapters using Java Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890833/message-channels-one-or-many)

And the [Dynamic TCP example using the Java DSL dynamic flow registration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced).

Dynamic WebService inbound is a bit more tricky because you have to register the new endpoints