# Encrypt mail password in Spring Boot + Spring Integration application

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, jasypt

My application is developed using **Spring boot**, this application also reading a mailbox, this mail reading part was implemented using **Spring Integration** framework.

I need to encrypt all passwords using in this application. I am using Jasypt library (http://www.jasypt.org/) for this encryption. All password encryptions are working fine, **except** the mail password.

**Problem**: That is, the mail password is sending as-is ( **without decryption**). So, mail authentication failed.

Code involves ALL other passwords are using ONLY spring boot, so there is ONLY one application context exists.
But, **mail reading part alone** was implemented by using Spring Integration framework. This configuration was done using an xml file,this xml file creates 2nd Application context. So, password decryption is **NOT accessible** for this 2nd application context.

Jasypt library related encryption code exists inside **1st application context**.

Will convert the below xml based configuration of Spring Integration into Java Based config solve the problem? ( Because, there will be only one application context).
If yes, can anyone provide the Java config **equivalent** for the below ( **prior to Java 8 version**)

```
<beans>
    <int:channel id="receiveChannel" /> 
    <mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="pop3ShouldDeleteTrue"
                                     store-uri="${mail.pop3.user.folder.uri}" 
                        channel="receiveChannel" 
                        should-delete-messages="false" 
                        should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
                        auto-startup="true"
                        java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">

        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="${actor.email.polling.interval}"> 
        </int:poller>   
    </mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <context:property-placeholder location="file:./application-${env}.properties" local-override="true" />
    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties"> 
        <prop key="${mail.socketFactory}">false</prop> 
        <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop> 
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">${mail.store.protocol}</prop>
    </util:properties> 
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it in a second application context?

You can use `@ImportResource` in your Spring Boot app to pull the xml into the main Boot context.

See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/barrier/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/barrier/Application.java#L33) for an example.

If you want to convert to Java Configuration, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826864/spring-multiple-imapadapter/32827733#32827733) has an example.