# Spring Boot dynamic context creation (parent/child)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, ioc-container

I am using **Spring Boot** with Spring Integration and I would like to load different properties for each `child()` context. Is this possible?

At this moment, I am working with this: (only the most relevant lines)

```
SpringApplicationBuilder parent = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class);
// Child sources (Will be inside a loop)
// Load the different environment ??
parent.child(ConfigDynamic.class); 
// End of child loading

parent.run(args);
```

I have reviewed the SpringApplicationBuilder `child()` method and the properties are propagated from the father to the child:

```
child.properties(this.defaultProperties).environment(this.environment)
.additionalProfiles(this.additionalProfiles);
```

But I need to load some properties dynamically like the following example:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext parent = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class);
parent.setId("parent");
Properties props = new Properties();
StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext child = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
child.setId("child" + ++n);
child.setParent(parent);
child.register(ConfigDynamic.class);        
// populate properties for this adapter
props.setProperty("prop1", myProp1);
props.setProperty("prop2", myProp2);
env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
child.setEnvironment(env);
child.refresh();
```

Extracted from this example: [Spring multiple imapAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826864/spring-multiple-imapadapter/32827733#32827733)

The reason to this is because some Spring Integration components will be loaded dynamically from a configuration file. Thus, I need to create different contexts with the dynamic components.

Any idea will be appreciated, thank you

**Edit 1:**

I updated the example:

```
SpringApplicationBuilder parent = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class);

for start    
SpringApplicationBuilder child = parent.child(DynamicConfig.class);    

//Properties creation..
child.context().getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
child.run(args);    
end for

parent.run(args);
```

But now, the `child()` context is null before `run()` method and raises a NPE.

**Edit 2: (Working)**

```
SpringApplicationBuilder parent = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class);

for start    
SpringApplicationBuilder child = parent.child(DynamicConfig.class);    

PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("dynamicProps", props);  
StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
child.environment(env);
child.run();    
end for

parent.run(args);
```

The last thing that I definitely do not understand is why I need a parent context even if all my `@Component` and `@Configuration` are Spring Integration components and could be loaded as `child()`. Is the parent context the place to put bus/or component to communicate different children? I suposse that could be a memory problem loading several singletons for each context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work...

```
SpringApplicationBuilder child = builder.child(ConfigDynamic.class);
...
child.context().getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
...
child.run();
```

Comment: child() raises null pointer exception. I updated the question.