# Hundrets of in and output - channel for Spring Integration SFTP

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I´m looking for an smart idea how to handle a lot of channels in and output in Spring Integration with the sftp adapter.

My principlestructure for the folders is like, which I can´t change!

```
/
/user_1 
 /businessprocess_1
   /input
   /output
 /businessprocess_2
   /input
   /output
 /and so on...
/user_2
 /businessprocess_1
   /input
   /output
 /businessprocess_2
   /input
   /output
 /and so on...
.... for 50 User...
```

now every time a file is put in buisnessprocss_1/input a service specific activator is called, handles the file and should write the answer to the corresponding /output folder

The Problem is the amount of in/outputchannels adapter and serviceactivator specifications in the applications context. That looks like an configuration apocalypse going to happen.

Any Ideas / Solutions ?

greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the endpoints programmatically rather than defining each one statically; use the new [flow registration mechanism in the Java DSL](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/27/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-candidate-1-is-available).

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826864/spring-multiple-imapadapter) shows another technique, using child contexts for mail inbound adapters.