# spring boot mail receiver with database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

hi i'm trying to read the end users mailbox by using spring mail integration. I have used following code it's working fine.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ImapTestApplication {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(ImapTestApplication.class, args);
              ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/gmail-imap-idle-config.xml");

            DirectChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("receiveChannel", DirectChannel.class);
            inputChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
                public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                    System.out.println("===================================");
                    System.out.println("Message: " + message);
                    System.out.println("===================================");
                }
            });
    }
```

And my xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util">

    <int:channel id="receiveChannel" />
    <!-- replace 'userid and 'password' with the real values -->
    <int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
            store-uri="imaps://mailaddress:password@host:993/inbox"
            channel="receiveChannel"
            auto-startup="true"
            should-delete-messages="false"
            should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
            java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"/>

    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imaps.auth">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
    </util:properties>

</beans>
```

In my application i have more than 100 users mailbox information in my database. So how i need to configure from my database. And also in runtime if user change the mail setting like password change it should be perform my mail receiver as well, I try to implement using Spring Integration Java DSL
but i cant use the imap settings from user mail database.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no easy way to do that with XML configuration.

Se some example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp

A new application context is created for every customer.

With Java DSL and its dynamic flows feature it is much easier to cook some `IntegrationFlow` from any arbitrary code at runtime.

You also can have them mapped to those users to be able to destroy and create a new one when properties are changed.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any sample code or detailed doc JavaDsL with IMAP mail service?

Comment: See here in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mail.html#java-dsl-configuration. And here as a test suite: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-mail/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/mail/dsl/MailTests.java

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826864/spring-multiple-imapadapter/32827733#32827733). It taks the dynamic-ftp approach for mail adapters using child contexts and Java Configuration, but I agree with Artem, dynamic DSL is the best solution now.